# Is there a way to convert/export tracking files (.trc files) from media cybernetics Image Pro Plus to a .mat file type?

Tags: matlab, import, bioinformatics, data-importer

I am a biology graduate student trying to export these files so that they can be used with a matlab based automated behavior classification software JAABA. It looks like there is no direct way to save .trc files as .mat (http://www.mediacy.com/imageproplus/specifications). At the very least I would like to figure out a way to read the format of the .trc files so that I could write a script to get them to make sense for JAABA. If anyone is familiar with either of these programs or both, or could simply point to a good way to write an importer (definitely outside of my skill set) I would be very grateful.

Comment: Below is a link to a function by Jérémie Guignard for importing .trc files to cell arrays in Matlab:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48919-readtrc-read-r-s-trc-files-into-a-matlab-cell-array

If it works for your need, you could then save your cell arrays as a .mat file.

Comment: Have you found a useful solution to this, drtran? I've tried that TRC file linked above, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: No it did not work